# Define Python function and print output in terminal

Tags: python, macos, function, terminal, output

Very basic question probably but I cannot find the answer. I have created a python program called "test.py." It contains the following code:

```
def test():
    print 'test'
```

I would like to run this program in my terminal (Mac) and have 'test' printed in the terminal. When I run the program as follows:

```
python test.py
```

it seems as if the program is executed but it does not print 'test'. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are not actually executing anything when you call your Python script. You simply have a method that is defined inside `test.py`.

You will actually have to call this method somewhere. If you are looking to execute code when you call `test.py`, you will need to put this at the bottom of your script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Per the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Answer (score 3):

You just define test function, you need to call it. There are 2 ways:
1. Call directly:

```
def test():
    print 'test'

test()
```

2. Call inside a **main** check (mostly use because when someone import your test.py, it will not call test() function):

```python
def test():
    print 'test'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function. Something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  test()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to call that function, the easiest way to get the output, is by calling it. Add this line in somewhere before or after the function definition.

```
test()
```

However, a better practice would be put this inside an if block ([reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do))

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `if __name__ == "__main__"` is the part that runs when the script is run from (say) the command line using a command like python `python test.py`.

   2.You can call directly:

   ```
   def test():
       print 'test'

   test()
   ```